# Use ModelListType withour relation in SonataAdmin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Is possible to use ModelListType::class without relation ?
i try this way

$admin = different Admin object

```
  ->add('partner',ModelListType::class,[
                'mapped'=>false,
                'class'=>User::class,
                'sonata_admin'=>admin,
                'model_manager'=>admin->getModelManager()
            ])
```

But still have

Impossible to invoke a method ("id") on a null variable.
in src/Resources/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/views/Form/form_admin_fields.html.twig (line 59)

I Need this field for js manipulation is not field and not mapped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem, mine is mapped but on a method not an actual attribute. This might work for you ass well. Add this a the bottom of configureFormFields method.

```
 if($this->hasFormFieldDescription('partner')) {
   $formFieldDescription =$this->getFormFieldDescription('partner');
   $formFieldDescription->setAssociationAdmin($this->getConfigurationPool()->getAdminByClass(User::class));
 }
```